# How to transition the activity from top to bottom and viceversa?

Tags: android-animation

Can anybody tell how to transition the activity from top to bottom in Android, perhaps with an example?

Comment: yes ..I need top to bottom animation while entering activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define an animation in res/anim/slide_in_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

and another at res/anim/slide_out_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

Then apply these after to call startActivity:

```
Intent i2 = new Intent(main.this, test.class);
startActivity(i2);
overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up );
```

Comment: this answer with some explanation would be great. Only code is not what people look for. If their would be some explanation we (beginners) would get something rich.