# Android slide activity transition without fade

Tags: android, android-transitions

I want to create an activity transition like the one shown in the Full Screen section of [this page](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions) of the Material Design spec. I'm hoping I can get a press of the FAB to spread with a circular reveal across the bottom of the view and then transition to the new activity with a slide up from the bottom.

As a first step towards this goal I've used a `Slide` transition with a `Gravity.BOTTOM` to animate in the new Activity. This is working, but as well as the slide the incoming activity is fading in. In the animation on the spec the sliding activity is solid as it slides up, and I'm not sure how to achieve this effect. I've looked in the code for `Slide` and its parent `Visibility` and there is a method called `forceVisibility(int visibility, boolean isStartValue)`, but it's not part of the public API so I can't use it. The fact that it exists does suggest that what I want to do is possible (as does the animation on the Material Design guide), but I'm not sure what I need to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: overriding the default transition may be the best thing to do. Checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578059/make-activity-animate-from-top-to-bottom

Comment: @MichaelObi There goes my 'Tumbleweed' badge. ;-)  Thanks for the comment, I'll have a look.